# getting list elements as the csv column values

Tags: python, csv

`I have a get_values() which returns the coordinates in the form of a list[x0,y0]. My column names are as follows. I want to get the values for each column but it is stacking all the values in the columns x0,y0

```
fieldvalues =
["x0","y0","x1","y1","x2","y2","x3","y3","x4","y4","x5","y5","x6","y6","x7","y7","x8","y8","x9",
          "y9","x10","y10","x11","y11","x12","y12","x13","y13","x14","y14","x15","y15","x16","y16","x17","y17"]
```

I have tried this code

```
get_val = oneObject.get_values(currentFrameIndex)
for humanPos in get_val:
       fieldvalues.append(humanPos) 


with open("./pose_data.csv",mode ='w') as csvfile:
       wr = csv.writer(csvfile,dialect="excel")
       wr.writerows(fieldvalue)
```

get_val has values of the form - list  like [x0,y0] and so on upto [x17,y17]

the output of the current code :

```
x0  y0 x1 y1 x2 y2 ....x17 y17
0   1  
1   2
```

Desired output:

```
   x0  y0 x1 y1 x2 y2 ....x17 y17
    0  1  2  3  4  5  ....3    3
    1  2  5  5  5  6  ....4    1
```

I will appreciate your response. Thank you.

Comment: Your code block starts without context. The first line alone has three undeclared names. Please add all code required to reproduce the problem, all input data and the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use append function like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('AB'))
>>> df
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame([[5, 6], [7, 8]], columns=list('AB'))
>>> df.append(df2)
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
0  5  6
1  7  8
```

I hope this answers your question :)

Comment: my current code is stacking all the data in the first two columns only(skipping the rest columns) . I want it to print it the values column based.

Answer (score 0):

Initialized `fieldValues` with two level list:

```
fieldvalues =[["x0","y0","x1","y1","x2","y2","x3","y3","x4","y4","x5","y5","x6","y6","x7","y7","x8","y8","x9", "y9","x10","y10","x11","y11","x12","y12","x13","y13","x14","y14","x15","y15","x16","y16","x17","y17"]]
```

and keep appending row on it:

```
get_val = oneObject.get_values(currentFrameIndex)
fieldvalues[currentFrameIndex] = []
for humanPos in get_val:
   fieldvalues[currentFrameIndex] = fieldvalues[currentFrameIndex] + humanPos
```

Then iterate on `fieldvalues` & write rows on a file.

Comment: after adding [ ] it is stacking all the values under one column only. with this form [2 3 ] [ 2  4]